# Assessing normality in a two-way ANOVA using residuals

Tags: anova

I'm trying to assess normality in a two-way ANOVA. I have a 3 x 2 design. I have split the file by cells and used SPSS to create a new variable of the residuals. I have calculated the normality of the residuals in each cell using the Shapiro-Wilk. I have significant violations of normality. When I ran the normality tests on my normal data rather than the residuals, I have strong normality. I thought that in a two-way ANOVA testing normality with the residuals or the normal data gave the same result? Why are the two methods giving me different normality results? Which result should I use?
Thanks

Comment: The question looks promising but showing more details may be super useful. _When I ran the normality tests on my normal data rather than the residuals, I have strong normality._  It's better to test for normality, through the residuals and not through the response.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's better not to use tests of normality here. They are not very useful because they are conflated with sample size. Use quantile normal plots and so on.

Second, I'm not sure why you thought that normality testing the dependent variable and the residuals would give the same result. For ANOVA/OLS regression, it's the residuals that matter and there's no reason to expect the results to be the same. Indeed, while the results for normal/not normal on SW *may* be the same (or different) the distributions will never be exactly the same.